# Why is the copied XPATH not working for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a game and I need to get the boxed element using selenium. I'm using python 3.11 and MacOS with M2 chip. I'm also using Chrome Version 123.0.6312.59 [Link to picture of elements tab in inspect menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lrfS.png)
(They took down my question because of a similarity to a question involving Firefox, but this is different because it's Chrome).

I copied the XPATH and it gave me this:

`"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div"`.

Is this correct / any other ideas on how to access this element?

Comment: Never post code as images but rather as plain text. Questions must provide a [mcve] so please add code and html sample

Comment: Everything @LMC wrote is correct, plus see the duplicate link to learn how to account for the `iframe`.

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks this makes sense, however I can't seem to find the name of the iframe and the ID isn't working either - any ideas?

Comment: @BrendanGraziani: Not off the top of my head, but it's likely been asked/answered before.  Try searching more thoroughly than you did this time, and if that fails, ask a more specific question, include a [mcve], post code as text, not image, etc.   Good luck.